# Inclusionwise maximal linear subvarieties of a projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, grassmannian

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb P^n$ be a complex, projective variety. A linear subspace $L\subseteq\mathbb P^n$ will be called a maximal linear subspace of $X$ if $L\subseteq X$ and for any linear subspace $L'$ with $L\subseteq L'\subseteq X$, we have $L=L'$.

Let us denote by 
$$F_k(X):=\{ L\subseteq X \text{ linear subspace}, \dim(L)=k\}$$
 the Fano variety of $k$-planes in $X$, which is a subariety of the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $\mathbb P^n$. We set $F(X):=F_1(X)\mathrel{\dot\cup}\cdots\mathrel{\dot\cup} F_n(X)$. Then, consider in $F(X)$ the set of linear subspaces of $X$ which are maximal in the above sense, i.e. inclusion-wise maximal, not of maximal dimension. Denote this set by $\tilde F(X)$.

My question is: Is $\tilde F(X)$ an open subvariety of $F(X)$? Does anyone have an easy proof or a reference, in case it is?

Comment: Note that this is (roughly) equivalent to asking whether the image of
$$\{(L, M) \in F_k(X) \times F_{k+1}(X) \; | \; L \subseteq M \} \xrightarrow{\rm proj_1} F_k(X)$$
is always closed.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury: Interesting, I didn't see that angle. If I am not somehow mistaken, this is the image of a projective morphism, so it should be closed. Any flaws in that argument?